# How to run R with F5 key in vim?

Tags: r, vim

I have installed vim and R in xp ,how to write map command in _vimrc?
I have written some of the command  such as  `map <F5> :w<CR>:!R`,when i press F5,can i make R script run?

I edit a file in vim ,only online in it to test.

```
vim print.R  
print(1:10)
```

when i set `nnoremap <F5> :w\|!R<CR>` in _vimrc ,press f5  ,i can see Rterm but the `print.R` can't run,how can i do?

if i change the set command as `nnoremap <F6> :w\|!Rcmd BATCH<CR>`, i get the following output:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c (Rcmd BATCH)
no input file
shell returned 1
Hit any key to close this window...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
nnoremap <F5> :w\|!R<CR>
```

so after my answer, you edited your question, now try this:

```
nnoremap <F5> :w\|!R %<CR>
nnoremap <F5> :w\|!Rcmd %<CR>
```

whatever the executable file is, put after `!`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [quickrun](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3146), if you don't mind using plugins.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is the well known SingleCompile: http://www.topbug.net/SingleCompile

Answer (score 0):

I have this plugin just released for interfacing vim and interpreters like R or python:

https://github.com/iago-lito/intim/

- it wraps around a tmux session so that Vim and R stay independent
- provides updatable syntax highlighting
- reads help in a vim buffer
- customizable "hotkeys" can make it quite fast to send request about your script variables and the current state of your R session.

Try it out, and don't hesitate to file your first bug reports / feature requests on the repo :)